# Размер шрифта под размеры блока в Android

Tags: android, textview, android-textview

Возможно ли и как можно реализовать возможность текста елемента TextView увиличить и уменьшить под размеры самого View? Суть в том что размер блока зависит от размера устройства, на планшетах буквочки очень маленькие, а на телефоне большие, придусмотреть все варианты нет возможности, но и плюс к тому что одно слово на разных языках имеет разную длину, что тоже не всегда смотрится нормально... Может есть способ ростянуть содержимое прямо до краев блока какого бы размера он не был?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то так)

Я додумался только до одного решения, а именно переганять текст в Bitmap и вставлять в блок вместо TextView ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Реализация следующая: Делаем ImageView вместо TextView, создаем Bitmap где рисуем текст, соединяем их в одно, и ScaleType подбираем по желанию